# Sorting a string literal in C

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, string-literals

Suppose I have a string literal which is supplied at runtime:

```
const char *example_message
```

I would like to apply a sort to the characters in the string literal at runtime.

How can I do so?

I've tried copying the literal into an array but that doesn't work since it's size is not known at compiletime.

I cannot edit the string literal in place because they are immutable.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user15200182 For starters the C compiler can support variable length arrays. Another approach is to allocate a character array dynamically.

Comment: The size of a string literal is known at compile time

Comment: A *literal* is something whose value is expressed in its name. In `int x;`, `x` is not a literal because we do not know what its value is from the text `x`. `34` is a literal because we know its value is thirty-four from the characters used to write it. `"abc"` is a literal because we know it is a string with the characters “a”, “b” and “c” from the text used to write it. If somebody passes you a `const char *` named `message` that points to the first character of a string, that is not a literal because we do not know what is in it from the name. It is just a string, not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a variable length array if the compiler supports variable length arrays or you can allocate a memory for a character array dynamically and then use the array to sort characters of a string literal.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return *( const unsigned char * )a - *( const unsigned char *)b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *literal = "ZYX";
    size_t n = strlen( literal );

    puts( literal );
    
    char s1[ n + 1 ];
    strcpy( s1, literal );
    
    qsort( s1, n, sizeof( char ), cmp );
    
    puts( s1 );

    putchar( '\n' );
    
    puts( literal );

    char *s2 = malloc( n + 1 );
    strcpy( s2, literal );
    
    qsort( s2, n, sizeof( char ), cmp );
    
    puts( s2 );

    free( s2 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ZYX
XYZ

ZYX
XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

As the given character pointer is constant. So it immutable.

So, I can create a temporary character array dynamically or statically and copy the value in it. And then sort the temporary array using `qsort()` `c` library function.

Here is the code snippet for creating a temporary character array dynamically or statically.

```c
const char *str = "AZBCD";
int n = strlen(str);

char temp[n + 1];
strcpy(temp, str);
```

or

```c
const char *str = "AZBCD";
int n = strlen(str);


char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
strcpy(temp, str);
```

Here is the conclusive code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    int x = *( const unsigned char * )a;
    int y = *( const unsigned char * )b;
    /*
        For ascending order & descending order.
        Manipulate the below code and get your desire results.

        1) x < y
            a) if we return 1 then the string will sort descending order.
        2) x > y
            a) if we return 1 then the string will sort ascending order.

        Vice versa is also possible.
    */
    if(x > y) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "AZBCD";
    int n = strlen(str);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    char temp[n + 1];
    strcpy(temp, str);

    qsort(temp, n, sizeof(char), compare);

    printf("%s\n", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @klutt said in comments, the size of a string literal is known at compile time.  Also, there's no such thing as a "string literal which is supplied at runtime."

The direct way to define a `char[]` array with a copy of the contents of a literal is to use an initializer when defining the array:

```
char my_copy[] = "this is a literal";
```

If you wanted an uninitialized array, big enough to hold that string literal, you can use the `sizeof` operator:

```
char my_area[sizeof "this is a literal"];
```

If you meant something else by "string literal", try to remember that a literal is a compile time constant where the source code for that constant represents the value.  It's not just another name for a string.  Show the code you're trying to get working and maybe someone could be of more help.